# Logging not working in Stripes framework application

Tags: java, logging, log4j, stripes

In my Stripes Framework application, Logging is not getting logged on console.

stack: Apache Tomcat +jdk7+stripes 1.6

I am using the logger as:

```
import net.sourceforge.stripes.util.Log;
private static final Log logger = Log.getInstance(UserActionBean.class);
logger.debug("In Create User");
```

I have tried using the net.sourceforge.stripes.util.Log4JLogger but still nothing gets printed on the console.

I have all the jars in my lib and below is the commons-logging.properties

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=net.sourceforge.stripes.util.Log4JLogger
```

Below is log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.net.sourceforge.stripes=DEBUG
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you call `logger.debug()`.

In log4j.properties however, debug output is only enabled for the package `log4j.logger.net.sourceforge.stripes`. This concerns the Stripes framework packages itself.

You have to enable DEBUG logging for the package(s) that contain your own (ActionBean) classes. Let's say your `UserActionBean` is in a package `com.mybusiness.stripes.action` then in `log4j.properties` you need to include the line:

`log4j.logger.com.mybusiness.stripes.action=DEBUG`

Or a parent package:

`log4j.logger.com.mybusiness` to broaden the scope of a logging rule.

Alternatively you could set `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG`.